# On fix table header do not allow this element to go below tbody element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery in a fix element which is a table header, I am going to show you the current behavior and then I will tell you the behavior I need

Here is the regular state

[image]

then when you scroll down the page, it looks like this which is perfect

[image]

but if you keep scrolling, it table header does not respect the last element in the table and keeps going down the page

[image]

so at the end it will look like that, only the table header.

What I need is to keep that table header scrolling down until it reachs with the last element on the table or something like that.

I did a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tdkwrde4/ where clearly the yellow element should stop when the table disappear from the screen.

Is it clear?

Here is the code

```
var fixTableHeader = function() {

    $('.grid-header').first().addClass('sticky');

    var sticky = $('.sticky'),
        stickyOffset = sticky.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= stickyOffset) {
          sticky.addClass('fixed')
      } else {
          sticky.removeClass('fixed');
      }
    });
};
```

css

```
.sticky {
    background: orange;
}

.fixed {
    border-width: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 1.3%;
}
```

any recommendation ?

Comment: You're currently adding `.fixed` when the user scrolls past the top of the table. So use the exact same technique to remove `.fixed` when the user scrolls past the bottom of the table.

Comment: (You might also want to add some padding to the top of the table when the header is in the `.fixed` state, so the first row doesn't drop out of view behind the header)

Comment: @DanielBeck can you write some lines of code? please. I am trying in my own right now but I will like to see your solution, as soon as I get mine I will post it.

Comment: Not hard to compare to table height or to position of an element right after table

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but that's a trivial enough derivation of what you already have that I'm not very much inclined to spoonfeed you teh codez.